# UUID into unsigned int

Tags: c++, compression, uuid

Is there anywhere to compress/convert/encode/encrypt a UUID into an unsigned int?

I read UUID's from a sql table, the history is ugly and i can not change... I have only an unsigned int to store it in. This is C++ in case that makes a difference

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks
Reza

Comment: A UUID is 16 bytes; the largest integral primitive I'm aware of in mainstream compilers is 8 bytes. How do you expect to do this without losing data?

Comment: What kind of UUID? That's all that matters. If it's more than 32 bits of information you won't be able to fit it inside an `unsigned int`.

Comment: I understand the above mentioned limitations. May be another way I can solve the problem is to use something other than a UUID to ensure uniqueness...

Comment: @reza : Ultimately there's no way to do what you want without data loss. **You** have to decide to what extent the data loss is acceptable.

Comment: string CRC is uniqueness enough...

Comment: I agree that CRC128 might be enough, but not standard CRC32... ;-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CRC32 of the UUID (I assume you mean 32-bit integer). There's obviously the potential for collisions, but if there's a collision it should be rare enough you can just fix it manually.

Note that if this is MS SQL Server, you can use the `CHECKSUM` function to do a crc32 hash on the server to update your table.

Comment: You can do a query after the fact to see if there are any collisions. `select count(crc_value),uuid_value group by uuid_value having count(crc_value)>1`

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, you *will* lose information translating a 128-bit UUID to a narrower integer type.

If you want to guarantee uniqueness -- well, that's what UUIDs are for, after all, and you might just consider keeping the information in UUID format.

If you can settle for a low chance of collisions (two distinct UUIDs mapping to the same integer), there are several things you can try.

Use as big an integer type as you can.  If your compiler supports an unsigned 64-bit integer type (`unsigned long long` or whatever Microsoft calls it), use that.

`xor`ing the upper and lower 64-bit halves of the UUID should give you a reasonably decent hash.

If there's some kind of order (non-randomness, predictability) in the UUID values that makes that unsuitable, you can compute an md5 or sha-1 hash and discard all but 64 bits.  It doesn't matter which bits you discard.

If you're restricted to a 32-bit integer, you can `xor` the four 32-bit quarters of the UUID together, or discard all but 32 bits of the md5 or sha-1 hash.

Note that in the case of 32-bit integers, you could conceivably have a collision on your first two samples, but that's unlikely.  The likelihood of a collision rises to roughly 50% with a number of samples somewhere around the square root of the total number of possibilities, so if you have 100,000 random 32-bit numbers, it's likely that two of them will be the same.  See the [Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a hash function to transform the UUID to always positive number and store the number into the unsigned int?

Comment: md5 is 128 bits, do you have any recommendations?