# PHP base convert as unique id

Tags: php, unique

I'm using `uuid` from cassandra which generates this utf8 string:

`f6195c60-364e-11e2-b43e-c78503d589ce21rvhf9q21`

But i need to shorten it to somwhere between 4-6 letters, after some googling i found out about

`base_convert($id, 5, 36);`

Which does just that, but is it really going to stay unique?

This is probably a dumb question, but i need some explanation.

Comment: No it won't, perhaps this will help you some what. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828702/uuid-into-unsigned-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cassandra Wiki:

```
[...] UUIDs are represented by a 32 digit hexadecimal number in the form of xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As I see in your example UUID, there are some ridiculous characters like `r`, `v`, `h` and `q`.
I assume this caused by a mistake and will try to answer your question:

If you want to use `base_convert`, first of all you should omit the hyphens.

The `base_convert()` function signature is as follows:

```
string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )
```

Note that the `frombase` argument in your case should be 16 not 5, that's because UUIDs are 32 digit hexadecimal numbers.

And finally, the maximum number you can use as `tobase` is `36` (according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)).

So the best thing you can do is:

```
base_convert($yourNumber, 16, 36);
```

and the converted number length will be more than 4-6 characters.
So it's not possible to shrink the UUID and still have a unique number by using `base_convert()`.

Technically if you assume the UUID as a hexadecimal number and convert that to base 128, you'll have a 4 letters length result.

Answer (score 3):

This is not utf8 string. UTF8 is character encoding and UUID perfectly fits even 7bit encodings. `base_convert()` will  not work because UUID is not a number (at least due to `-`). And no, shortening it to 4 letters will not make it any better. Assuming you use 0-9 and a-z gives 36!4 combinations only so the collision is quite likely (and who knows how you generate that ID and how often). In general - if you want unique - **make it** unique (like store already generated IDs in DB so you know when collision occurs). Now you are just hoping and try to cross your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into uniqid() function that is built into PHP?  I believe it by default returns a 14 character string and gives you the ability to enter a custom prefix to add additional uniqueness.

You can find more information about uniqid() here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php